# Middle-straight starting with an ace?

Tags: no-limit

I was watching a tournament and was surprised by the outcome of this hand

[image]

He wins the hand with a 9 high straight? So A-6-7-8-9? I thought ace could only be used in A2345 or TJQKA. Am I missing something?

Comment: feel free to leave an answer on your own question. looks like you have found the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the game was shortdeck, which is played with a 36-card deck, meaning: all of the 2s through 5s removed. So if you ever see weird straights in a tournament stream, it's shortdeck (commonly abbreviated by SD)

Comment: And also keep an eye on the different ranking of hands in SD games

Comment: Good point, flushes scoring higher than full houses and a three of a kind higher than a straight